# Почему объект, возвращаемый из функции, остается валидным?

Tags: c++, ссылки, неопределённое-поведение

Ожидается, что `a` будет очищен после завершения `GetA()`, а ссылка на него в методе `main` будет невалидной.

```
class A
{
 public:
 std::string str;
 void Print()
 {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
 }
};

A GetA()
{
  A a;
  a.str = "this is my string";
  return a;
}

int main()
{
  A a = GetA();
  a.Print();
  return 1;
}
```

Но в результате в консоли получаю `this is my string`.

Comment: "*ссылка на него в методе main*" -  нет там никаких ссылок, а если бы и была, то у вас не было бы никакой возможность проверить,  валидная она или нет

Comment: @VTT как тогда правильно назвать `a` в методе `main`?

Comment: `a` - это полноценный объект класса `A`, а не ссылка на такой объект

Comment: @VTT понял. три года джавы дают о себе знать, уже привык что `A a = new A()`, в джаве `a` будет ссылкой на экземпляр. Как от этого теперь отвыкнуть.

Comment: @raviga но ведь в Java его никто и не удалит при выходе из функции! К чему конкретно в этом коде нужно привыкать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, к джаве удаление с этого вопроса не имеет никакого отношения. Речь идет о правильном наименовании переменных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом предложении

```
A a = GetA();
```

создается новый объект с именем `a` на основе вызова конструктора копирования.

Тот объект, который возвращается из функции, будет удален по завершению предложения

```
A a = GetA();
```

после того, как он будет скопирован в новый объявляемый (создаваемый) объект.

И в последующем предложении используется именно этот новый объект

```
a.Print();
```

Нигде в вашем коде не валидные ссылки не используются.

Чтобы сделать ссылку не валидной, просто из функции `GetA` возвращайте ссылку на локальный объект.

```
A & GetA()
{
  A a;
  a.str = "this is my string";
  return a;
}
```

В этом случае компилятор может выдать предупреждение, что возвращается ссылка на локальный объект.

Comment: понял, спасибо. А каким образом я могу достичь результата, чтобы воспроизвести ситуацию когда у меня ссылка буде не валидной? Когда `a` будет очищено в конце функции? Если убрать конструктор копирования?

Comment: @raviga Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: Во-первых ответ на проблему, которой нет. Во-вторых объяснение происходящего (в реалиях современного С++) неверное. Тут внутри функции `GetA` создается объект с размещением в вызывающей функции `main` и никакого копирования (или перемещения) не происходит.

Comment: @VTT можно подробнее? возвращаемый из `GetA` `a` не копируется, а существует в области видимости функции `main`? не очень понял *создается объект с размещением в вызывающей функции main и никакого копирования (или перемещения) не происходит*

Comment: @raviga Место под него выделяется в `main`, но создается объект внутри `GetA`. Грубо говоря, вместо создания трех объектов создается только один минуя все промежуточные копирования.

Comment: @VTT: "Guaranteed copy elision" в С++17 гарантирует, что операнд `return` будет напрямую использоваться в качестве инициализатора для объекта приемника. То есть `a` из `GetA` будет выступать в качестве инициализатора для `a` из `main`. Так что копирование/перемещение здесь запросто может быть. Избежать копирования может RVO (и оно здесь почти гарантировано сработает). Но RVO не гарантируется. Так что в данном случае в С++17 мы получим либо перемещение, либо RVO. Но гарантий, что напрямую создается объект в `main` нет.

Comment: Вот если бы мы сделали `return "this is my string";`, тогда бы эта С-строка тоже напрямую выступила инициализатором для `a` из `main`, как я сказал выше.

Comment: Для случая возвращения **ссылки** на локальный объект компилятор GCC (например) вообще сделает `xor     eax, eax;   ret;` То есть не просто выдаст предупреждение, а еще и специально вернет наверх "нулевую" ссылку.

Comment: @AnT Хотя таких гарантий и нет, но все компиляторы стараются как можно агрессивней устранять промежуточные объекты и на практике имеет смысл закладываться как раз на отсутствие move (а заодно и еще одного деструктора).

Comment: @VTT В любом случае конструктор копирования должен быть доступен. Если он не доступен, то никакой объект напрямую не создаться. Так что правильно будет говорить в терминах копирования.